# Issue with Font and underline in HTML email

Tags: html, html-email

Wonder if anyone can help - I am testing an HTML email in various clients, it has a arial black set as a font, and the customer wanted the the underline taking off the link. All fine and dandy in browsers when i use the standard inline css to do this - However when I test in the clients the underline shows, after a bit of investigation it appears its arial black thats the issue. Is there anyway at all to use arial black and turn the underline off ?

```
<a href="" target="_blank" style="font-family: Arial black, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color:#000;text-decoration: none;">blah blah</a>
```

Comment: Strange, this should work. What happens if you take the `text-decoration` into the front? It could be that the space in "Arial Black" screws up the parsing. What clients is this in? Also, be aware that Arial Black may not be installed on all clients.

Comment: @owen have you solved it yet ?
I really need to know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Put 'Arial Black' in quotes and see if that helps, like so:

```
style="font-family: 'Arial Black', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;/* ... */"
```

With the CSS font-family property, it is best practice to put quotes around font names that contains spaces.

Comment: hi, thanks - I gave that a go but the issue still seems to be there. I wonder if it's a wider issue in the mail - I'll have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Some email clients will not allow quotes in the font-family declaration.

Some email clients will disregard the font-family declaration and use the font declaration.

try:

```
style="font: 14px Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; font: 14px &quot;Arial Black&quot;Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; font-family: &quot;Arial Black&quot;Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;"
```

The main issue is the Arial Black font, of course.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, the problem is that Arial Black is a two word font name.  A lot of e-mail clients do not support font names with more than one word.  It doesn't matter if you use "quotes" , 'single quotes', nothing.  Just find a replacement font with a one word name.

See the email standards project for confirmation:

http://www.email-standards.org/clients/gmail/#font-family-quotes

This page applies to gmail, but I had the same problem in other email clients including hotmail and godaddy email.